# How to generate smooth flow pager with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation

For these page numbers below:
1 2 3 4 5 6

When 6 is clicked,7 should come out from right side,and 1 should hide into left,so on.

How to create such kind of effect with jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... jQuery TOOLS [Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html) looks nice. It has [Demo](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/edit.html) for adding/removing items dynamically.

I don't think it's so complicated to modify that example to suit your needs, btw. Just change the `append` in addItem to load your next item via AJAX (that's what you want, right?) and bind it to the last item (you can get it easily via its API). And removeItem... I don't even think you need it.

Maybe some other tweaks would be needed - but it still seems easier than rolling your own.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Karmic Flow](http://www.karmagination.com/blog/2009/09/10/karmic-flow-0-1-content-slider-for-karmagination-jquery/)

Comment: No,its menus are fixed,but I need new menu items to come out on the fly.